# Css dynamically setting <h> tag type

Tags: html, css

If you have the code in some html:

```
<h1> Caption </h1>
```

Is there a way to change it by css to:

```
<h2> Caption </h2>
```

Comment: With CSS you can style your `h1` tag the same style that `h2` has, but you can't change the actual tag from `h1` to `h2`. CSS is for styling.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, CSS is a language for styling elements only, and can't do more than that.
What you want to acheive can only be done by javascript.

Comment: Actually he can't change the tag with JS either.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change your tag from h1 to h2 using css. CSS is for styling elements, it can not not be used to change contents of your tag.

My suggestion is to use javascript for content manipulation.